# dynamic random rows from table database

Tags: php, mysql, random

Consider that I have 3 question types; true or false `ToF`, multi-choice `MC` and complete.

Now I want to randomly get 10 questions true or false, 5 questions multi-choice and 2 questions complete ( these numbers are not static and it will be variables to the execute function ).

My table is something like this:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------+
| id  | question                                           | type     | examId |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------+
| 1   | true or false question 1                           | ToF      |     1  |
| 2   | true or false question 2                           | ToF      |     1  |
| 3   | true or false question 3                           | ToF      |     1  |
| 4   | true or false question 4                           | ToF      |     1  |
| 5   | true or false question 5                           | ToF      |     1  |
| 6   | true or false question 6                           | ToF      |     1  |
| 7   | true or false question 7                           | ToF      |     1  |
| 8   | true or false question 8                           | ToF      |     1  |
| 9   | true or false question 9                           | ToF      |     1  |
| 10  | true or false question 10                          | ToF      |     1  |
| 11  | true or false question 11                          | ToF      |     1  |
| 12  | true or false question 12                          | ToF      |     1  |
| 13  | multi choice question 1                            | MC       |     1  |
| 14  | multi choice question 2                            | MC       |     1  |
| 15  | multi choice question 3                            | MC       |     1  |
| 16  | multi choice question 4                            | MC       |     1  |
| 17  | multi choice question 5                            | MC       |     1  |
| 18  | multi choice question 6                            | MC       |     1  |
| 19  | multi choice question 7                            | MC       |     1  |
| 20  | multi choice question 8                            | MC       |     1  |
| 21  | complete question 1                                | complete |     1  |
| 22  | complete question 2                                | complete |     1  |
| 23  | complete question 3                                | complete |     1  |
| 24  | complete question 4                                | complete |     1  |
| 25  | complete question 5                                | complete |     1  |
| 26  | complete question 6                                | complete |     1  |
| 27  | complete question 7                                | complete |     1  |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------+
```

What I tried so far is to write query for every type like that

```
SELECT * FROM question WHERE type = 'ToF' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10
SELECT * FROM question WHERE type = 'MC' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5
SELECT * FROM question WHERE type = 'complete' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2
```

Can I do it with only one query?

Is it good to get all the result sorted by type and then by PHP get the random result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all in one query . . . even the final randomization:

```
(SELECT * FROM question WHERE type = 'ToF' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10
) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM question WHERE type = 'MC' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5
) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM question WHERE type = 'complete' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY rand();
```

This is a reasonable approach -- if you have just a handful of pre-known types.

Comment: the types are static so it's the answer i want , thanks :)